# AppStore Connect - can't provide information for test flight build

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

[image]

I've uploaded an Appstore build to release in test flight. But It showing a warning asking to complete test information... . But all the followed fields are disabled. Any idea why? I'm not able to find why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be logged in with an user account which has the access rights to change those information. I made the same error, I added my private AppleID as testuser and then I got an eMail which invitation link where I had to sign in with my private AppleID-account. Then I went back to AppStoreConnect and couldn't edit anything, because I was logged in with my private AppleID. I logged out and logged in with Administrator AppleID and everything worked again. :-D